# Git alias with bash script errors out on variable modification

Tags: regex, bash, git, alias

My git branch name:

```
feature/ACD-1706_new-api-call
```

If I run this script in the console, it works properly:

```
bash -l -c 'current_branch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" && no_feature=${current_branch##*/} && no_underscore=${no_feature%%_*} && history -s "git commit -m \"$no_underscore | " && echo "Press UP to start commit command:" && echo "" && read -e -p "> " && eval "$REPLY"'
```

It drops me in a prompt that helps me auto-generate a commit message based on the feature branch name.

```
> bash -l -c 'current_branch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" && no_feature=${current_branch##*/} && no_underscore=${no_feature%%_*} && history -s "git commit -m \"$no_underscore | " && echo "Press UP to start commit command:" && echo "" && read -e -p "> " && eval "$REPLY"'
Press UP to start commit command:

>
```

But if I turn it into a git alias, the script errors out.

```
auto-message = !bash -l -c 'current_branch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" && no_feature=${current_branch##*/} && no_underscore=${no_feature%%_*} && history -s "git commit -m \"$no_underscore | " && echo "Press UP to start commit command:" && echo "" && read -e -p "> " && eval "$REPLY"'
```

```
> git auto-message
bash -l -c 'current_branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) && no_feature=${current_branch: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash -l -c 'current_branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) && no_feature=${current_branch: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: Git eats one layer of backslash from its configuration files (and treats double quotes interestingly), so if the command to feed to bash is, say, `bash -c "echo \"hello\""`, you need to set the config file to read: `!bash -c \"echo \\\"hello\\\"\"`

Answer (score 2):

Using `git commit`'s `-e` option would be far simpler if you just want to seed the commit message with some initial text. It also allows the user use their text editor of choice, rather than forcing `readline` on them.

```
git commit -em "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD | sed 's|.*/||; s|_.*$||;' )"
```

(One drawback is that this starts with a temporary file that contains the `-m` argument, so simply quitting the editor without saving isn't sufficient to abort a commit. You have to explicitly save an empty file to do that.)

This, then, is much easier to quote properly:

```
auto-message = !git commit -em "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD | sed 's|.*/||; s|_.*$||;')"
```

Comment: Nitpick: `${no_feature%%_*}` removes from the end, so the result of the substitutions is `ACD-1706` for the example; your sed command leaves `new-api-call` instead.

Comment: Nice simple solution. I suggest adding `s/$/ |/` at the end of the `sed` command to preserve the full behaviour from the OP's question. If you do so, you also have to add `\"` outside the existing quotes: `auto-message = !git commit -em \""$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD | sed 's|.*/||; s|_.*$||; s/$/ |/')"\"`

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly a case of having to escape the right character here or there.

I suggest a simpler solution, also suggested by @user7369280 at the same time I posted the original version of this answer: create file `git-auto-message` somewhere on your PATH with these contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o errexit

current_branch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"
no_feature=${current_branch##*/}
no_underscore=${no_feature%%_*}
history -s "git commit -m \"$no_underscore | "
echo "Press UP to start commit command:"
echo ""
read -e -p "> "
eval "$REPLY"
```

Make this file executable

```
chmod 755 /path/to/git-auto-message
```

And then

```
git auto-message
```

will run that script with the same behaviour your original command line had.

I just worked on troubleshooting your actual alias, and I found that the git alias syntax does not like having these symbols: `#`, `>`, `|`.

This variant works but loses some of your features:

- It does not remove the path at the beginning of the branch name. I have not found a way to search for the string up to the `/` using bash syntax that git aliases accept.
- It uses `-` instead of `|` to separate the branch name from the rest of the commit.
- It uses `$` instead of `>` for the prompt.

Revised alias:

```
auto-message = !bash -l -c 'current_branch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" && no_feature=${current_branch} && no_underscore=${no_feature%%_*} && history -s "git commit -m $no_underscore - " && echo "Press UP to start commit command:" && echo "" && read -e -p "_ " && eval "$REPLY"'
```

Answer (score 1):

A different solution. This doesn't uses aliases, but just uses a script.

Create a file in your path with the name `git-auto-message` (no extension!) with the following content:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

#current_branch="feature/ACD-1706_new-api-call"
current_branch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"
no_feature=${current_branch##*/}
no_underscore=${no_feature%%_*}

read -p "Complete commit message (empty cancels) \"$no_underscore | " msg
echo
# remove leading whitespaces
msg="${msg#"${msg%%[![:space:]]*}"}"
# remove trailing whitespaces
msg="${msg%"${msg##*[![:space:]]}"}"
if [ -n "$msg" ]; then
    git commit -m "$no_underscore | $msg"
fi
```

Make the script executable.

Then you can call `git auto-message`. Git realizes, that it doesn't have an internal command named `auto-message` and that there is no alias with that name. So it searches the path for an executable named `git-auto-message`. So the script gets executed.

While aliases are great for smaller things, this feature allows to create rather complex functionalities.

---

Updated script, as I missed, that you want to add additional text.